# Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to bound $e$

Tags: real-analysis

1. Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x}$, show that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.

This is proven.

2. Find the smallest $\alpha$ and largest $\beta$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\alpha}\leq e\leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\beta}$$

I can see how part 1 is related to 2, but I don't see a good approach to solve part 2. Any hints? thanks

Comment: Rearrange 2. after taking logarithms.

Comment: Hint: use 1. to obtain $(1+x) = \exp(...)$, then use this to replace $(1+\frac{1}{n})$ in 2. Also I think it's the largest $\alpha$ and the smallest $\beta$.